# Defining multiple type instances

Tags: typescript

I have to define ***let sideCalendar***, which returns the following console log:

[image]

Interface I currently have:

```
interface ICalendar{
  month: moment.Moment;
  calendar?: {
    [key: number]: moment.Moment | null;
    'firstDay': moment.Moment;
    'lastDay': moment.Moment;
  };
}
```

How can I define multiple arrays like these? For now, only one instance is described:

```
    [key: number]: moment.Moment | null;
```

Comment: That is an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types); it says that `calendar` could have any number of numeric keys and the properties at those keys would be `moment.Moment | null`.  What do you mean by "multiple arrays" and how does the highlighted index signature apply to your question?

Comment: Also note that any images of text should at least be accompanied by the text content as plain text; see [ask].

Comment: What specific type instances are you looking for; do they differ by number of weeks?

Answer (score 0):

If you try what you're trying to do TypeScript will narrow the `Record` value type to what's common. For example:

```
type A = Record<number, string | number>;
type B = Record<number, boolean | string>;
type C = A & B;

const data: C = {
    42: 'foo'
};
```

The common type between `A` and `B` is `string`, so the value of the `42` property must also be a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the numbered keys will contain an array that has either `moment.Moment` or `null` in them, you will need to define it as `[key: number]: Array<moment.Moment | null>`:

```
interface ICalendar {
  month: moment.Moment;
  calendar?: {
    [key: number]: Array<moment.Moment | null>;
    'firstDay': moment.Moment;
    'lastDay': moment.Moment;
  };
}
```